# How to analyze this Diode Circuit by hand?

Tags: resistors, dc

[image: Circuit]

I need to analyze this circuit by hand, I'm a Mechanical Engineer, so I really have no idea what I'm doing here. I thought about doing the parallel of the 2 top resistances and same for the bottom ones, but that wouldn't work. How do I analyze this? I need to know whether or not the diode is conducting electricity and the intensity of current that goes through it.

Sorry if any mistakes language-wise are made, I don't know the technical terms for this stuff in English. Cheers.

EDIT:
Assumed it was off, calculated the Voltage on the left and on the right of the diode, it's 0.25V, therefore not conducting.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: What do you need to calculate?  you can't treat the top two (equally the bottom two) as in parallel due to the diode. The ANODE of the diode is held at 2.5V and the cathode is lower & thus there will be some current flow through the diode

Comment: That is exactly how you should do it. Be careful though, if you are supposed to be using the "ideal" diode model, where diodes conduct with ANY forward voltage, than it will be on. It depends on what model you are supposed to be using.

Answer (score 2):

"Analyze" is really quite general. What are you specifically looking for? Usually, with diode circuits you start with a guess: is the diode conducting or not? Let's guess that it is.

If the diode is conducting, in a simple circuit such as this, you can replace it with a .6V (or whatever your diode drop is) voltage source and proceed with nodal or loop circuit techniques. After you've done this "analysis" using whatever technique, check against your initial guess: is the diode indeed conducting? If not, start over with the assumption that it is not conducting.

Comment: Or you could do it the other way.  Assume that it's off and see if the voltage across it would keep it off.  If not, then assume that it's on and do it again.  This has the advantage of doing the easy step first, in case it's all you need.

Comment: That worked fine. Assumed it was off, calculated the Voltage on the left and on the right of the diode, it's 0.25V, therefore not conducting.

Comment: @RafaeldeGomes, A real diode will conduct at 0.25V, just not very much current.

Answer (score 1):

So there are two voltage dividers.
It's 2.5 volts on one side and...
5V*(180/400) = 2.25 volts on the other side.
0.25 V across the diode.
We would then need to know the diode 
and the temperature.
But (at a guess) there might be 1-100 nA

Comment: Thanks for the help, forgot I could assume the Diode off and treat it as a voltage divider!

Answer (score 1):

The first question is whether this is for a class or real life. In a class, this sort of "figure out whether the diode is off or on" problem usually assumes an ideal diode with zero forward voltage drop.

The standard approach to solving these problems is guess and check. To be a valid solution, one of two conditions must be met:

1. The diode is on and the forward current (from anode to cathode) is positive.
2. The diode is off and the reverse voltage (from cathode to anode) is positive.

Let's try assuming the diode is off first. This gives us two voltage dividers. The one on the left (the anode) has two equal resistors, which gives us \$V_A = 2.5V\$. For the one on the right (the cathode), we have to calculate:

$$V_K = 5V * \frac{180}{220 + 180} = 2.25V$$

Condition 2 requires that \$V_K > V_A\$. This is not true, so the diode cannot be off\$^1\$. You can see this in the picture you posted, where the simulator shows current through the diode.

The next step is to assume the diode is on and verify that the current is positive. I'll leave that part to you. You'll need to find the voltage between the resistors and calculate the current through each resistor, then apply KCL to figure out the diode current.

\$^1\$A real diode does not turn on the moment \$V_D > 0V\$. Silicon diodes usually have a 0.6V - 0.7V forward voltage drop at low to moderate currents. There are also more complex ways to model a diode such as the [Shockley Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Shockley_diode_equation). A normal diode in your circuit would be unlikely to conduct, but a low-voltage Schottky diode at high temperature probably could.